# setting a solid line using dashes keyword argument in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been using the `dashes` keyword to setup custom linestyles in Matplotlib.  It's convenient to setup a list of tuples that represent different linestyles,

```
ds = [(4,2,4,2), (16,4,16,4)]
plt.plot( x, y, dashes=ds[0] )
```

for example.  I would like to setup up some tuple that produces a solid line when passed to a plotting command using the `dashes` keyword.  I've searched online but only found various ways of defining dashed and dotted lines.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solid line is `dashes=''` (an empty string).

As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10), dashes='')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: of course!  I tried `None` and 'none' but should have tried the empty tuple `()` which also works.  thanks.